# A more gentle word for the word "settled" in the context of payment

Tags: single-word-requests

I wrote the following sentence:

> We will proceed with the registration after the remaining balance is
>   ***settled***.

Somehow, I find that using the word *settled* in this sentence sounds a bit rude. This is especially true if we consider that I'm offering something in my previous sentence. I don't want to sound too demanding or make the reader feel bound to do anything.

I was thinking to replace *settled* with *made*. But still, *made* doesn't sound the best possible word.

What are the expressions that could be used in a sentence like this to say that an amount is to be paid and still sound gentle?

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but this question seems to be open to the ["bike shed question"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31253/the-bike-shed-problem-and-so) mentality that Stack Exchange eschews. That would make this question not constructive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you may want to change the entire sentence to read something like *We want to register you as soon as possible. Please help us by paying the remaining balance.*

Comment: Really good solution. I was writing up an answer but decided I preferred your version.

Comment: For me, "paying the remaining balance" is less gentle than "the remaining balance is settled".

Answer (score 8):

Please, please, please. There is nothing wrong with using the word *settled* there. Barrie's answer is merely a different way of stating a perfectly good sentence.

From NOAD:

> **settle** 1
>   *verb* 
>   1 [ with obj. ] resolve or reach an agreement about (an argument or problem): *every effort was made to settle the dispute.*
>   • end (a legal dispute) by mutual agreement: *the matter was settled out of court* | [ no obj. ] : he sued for libel and then settled out of court.
>   • determine; decide on: *exactly what goes into the legislation has not been settled* | [ no obj. ] : *they had not yet settled on a date for the wedding.*
>   • **pay (a debt or account)**: *his bill was settled by charge card* | [ no obj. ] : *I settled up with your brother for my board and lodging.*

[Emphasis my own.] It is clear that *settle* is used in the matter of debts. End of story.

Well, not entirely the end of the story. *Settled* is actually a less direct way of saying *paid*. So it is, in fact, the milder way of putting the matter. Your fourth or fifth dunning letter will contain phrases like "until this bill is paid" or "pay this amount now!" and so forth.

Comment: There is obviously nothing wrong, but nonetheless it sounds *rather rude* as OP stated...

Comment: @Pacerier: I disagree that it sounds rude. I think you're confusing the "pay a debt" sense with the "resolve or reach an agreement about (an argument or problem)" sense.

Comment: Apparently we couldn't get everyone to agree on a particular nuance, but if a signifiant population does *feel* that it sounds rude, isn't that sufficient to say that it does "sound rude"?

Comment: @Pacerier: By all means, fund a study. But a few random people going one way or the other does not a sample make.